# Face detection in android 4.2 doesn't work

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection

I created an application which use Camera face detection to know if someone uses application.

I followed instructions of Google doc and it works on Galaxy Tab 2 with android 4.0 or 4.1.

I just installed it on a Galaxy Tab 3 with Android 4.2 and recognition does not work.

I haven't any exceptions but onFaceDetection is never called.

Is something changed in 4.2 ?

Thanks

Comment: In Galaxy tab 3 there is "Smart stay" application which use the front webcam. I tried to disable it but it always doesn't work.

Someone has any other experience with this application ?